# How to find the longest matching substring in Go

Tags: string, algorithm, go, substring

What's the correct way to find the longest substring match?
I’ve been trying to find the longest substring match with the regexp package in Go: https://pkg.go.dev/regexp

Specifically the longest consecutive match of vowels in a string. Any length or combination of "aeiou".

Here's the code I have now. It works until the strings get too long resulting in a panic (over 1000). I start searching for the longest substring and return once a match is found.

```golang
s := "chrononhotonthuooaos"
for i := utf8.RuneCountInString(s); i >=0; i-- {
    exp := "[aeiou]{"
    exp += fmt.Sprint(i)
    exp += "}"
    regexStr := regexp.MustCompile(exp)
    longestStr := regexStr.FindStringSubmatch(s)
    if longestStr != nil {
        fmt.Println("longest submatch found:", longestStr)
        return utf8.RuneCountInString(longestStr[0])
    }
}
return 0
```

Comment: I don't know Golang but I would think you could just extract matches of the regex `\b[aeiou]+\b` and then find the longest among those. I suggest you edit the title and body of the question to only refer to strings of vowels. The broader question that is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting panics is because your are creating a new regex on **every** iteration — a 10,000 character string? That's 10,000 compiled regexen, and I'm pretty sure those get cached. Not to mention that regex compilation is expensive.

So why use a regex at all? Something like this is almost certainly faster, doesn't create any intermediate objects, and runs in O(n) time and O(1) space complexity. It will work for strings of any length whatsoever:

https://goplay.tools/snippet/nvZwWeEF8bC

```
func longest_vowel_run(s string) (string, int, int) {
    slen := len(s)
    bgn := 0
    end := 0
    max := 0
    x := 0
    y := 0

    // while we still have chars left...
    for x < len(s) {

        // find the first vowel
        for x < slen && !vowel[s[x]] {
            x++
        }
        // find the next non-vowel
        for y = x; y < slen && vowel[s[y]]; {
            y++
        }

        // if the current run is longer than the max run, update the max run
        if z := y - x; z > max {
            bgn = x
            end = y
            max = z
        }

        // pick up where we left off
        x = y

    }

    var maxRun string
    if max > 0 {
        maxRun = s[bgn:end]
    }

    return maxRun, bgn, end - 1
}

var vowel = map[byte]bool{
    'a': true, 'A': true,
    'e': true, 'E': true,
    'i': true, 'I': true,
    'o': true, 'O': true,
    'u': true, 'U': true,
}
```

Comment: I am more than happy to not use regex, that's just one of the ways I first thought of. It is definitely not a good solution.. I was hoping to learn a better method as well. What do you mean by "runs in O(n) time and space complexity" ?

Comment: @steve51516 — "Big O" notation is a way of talking about the worst-case performance of an algorithm. O(N) means that it varies linearly WRT the size of the input, O(1) is constant time, O(n²)  means that it varies exponentially with the size of the input), etc. See https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation for a rundown.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```golang
re := regexp.MustCompile(`[aeiou]+`)

matches := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1)
if len(matches) > 0 {
    longest := 0
    for i := range matches {
        if len(matches[i]) >= len(matches[longest]) {
            longest = i
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(matches[longest])
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/loxIsR3LMOM

---

Or, without regexp, you can do:

```golang
s := "chrononhotonthuooaos"

var start, end int
for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
    switch s[i] {
    case 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u':
        j := i + 1
        for ; j < len(s); j++ {
            switch s[j] {
            case 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u':
                continue
            }
            break
        }
        if j-i > end-start {
            start, end = i, j
        }
        i = j
    }
}

fmt.Println(s[start:end])
```

https://go.dev/play/p/XT5-pr3n0tl

Comment: @steve51516 `x+` is "match one or more `x`, prefer more". It's the same as `x{1,}`.

Comment: For your first regex solution, FindAllStringSubmatch returns [][]string, so I either had to specify the first index or use FindAllString. FindAllString works without the subslice.
What does the + do in the regex pattern `[aeiou]+` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. And although it is not as elegant as that of the companions, it works for me. https://go.dev/play/p/ZpZtqt92lvc

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"regexp"
)

func main() {

word := "chrononhotonthuooaos"
//word := "aeoihddkdhuaiahdnaanbcvuuooaaiieendjahaaaiiie"

// only vowels allowed (one or more)
re := regexp.MustCompile(`[aeiou]+`)

// to store max length slice of vowel macthes
max_length := 0

// position of the max lenghth slice inside `vowels_matches`
position := 0

// type ~~~~> [][]byte{}  all coincident slices inside another
vowels_matches := re.FindAll([]byte(word), -1)

for i := 0; i < len(vowels_matches); i++ {

    // Looking for the longest slice with vowels
    // so we are going to compare its lengths

    if len(vowels_matches[i]) > max_length {

        //if we find an slice longer max_length will take its value
        max_length = len(vowels_matches[i])

        // also we want to know the position, to pick after that slice in concret
        position = i
    }
}

// get that slice of bytes (the longest) an convert to string
result := string(vowels_matches[position])

fmt.Printf("%v type ~~~> %T\n", result, result)
```

}

Another option without using regex and with the help of little recursive function:https://go.dev/play/p/7sssSWv-0UL

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main() {

    word := "chrononhotonthuooaos"

    pattern := "aeiou"

    // we only want all vowels inside `word` variable
    // so `vowels` will append the positions inside `word`
    vowels := []int{}

    // slice of slices of vowel matches
    vowels_matches := [][]int{}

    // to store max length of vowel macthes slices
    max_length := 0

    // position of the max lenghth slice inside `vowels_matches`
    position := 0

    final_string_result := ""

    // append only vowels from `word`
    for i, vowel := range word {
        for _, v := range pattern {
            if v == vowel {
                vowels = append(vowels, i) //append the position of that vowel

            }
        }
    }

    vowels_matches = recursive(int(vowels[0]), vowels, vowels_matches)

    for i := 0; i < len(vowels_matches); i++ {
        if len(vowels_matches[i]) > max_length {
            max_length = len(vowels_matches[i])
            position = i
        }
    }

    for _, e := range vowels_matches[position] {
        final_string_result += string(word[e])
    }

    fmt.Println(final_string_result)

}

func recursive(valid int, vowels []int, vowels_matches [][]int) [][]int {

    temp := []int{}

    for i, value := range vowels {
        if value == valid+1 || i == 0 {
            valid = value
            temp = append(temp, value)
        } else {
            next_last := int(vowels[i:][0])
            new_slice := vowels[i:]
            vowels_matches = recursive(next_last, new_slice, vowels_matches)
        }
    }

    vowels_matches = append(vowels_matches, temp)

    return vowels_matches
}
```